# Sitemap for events2

Tags: typo3, seo, typo3-10.x

I use TYPO3 v10.4.24, events2 v7.1. and the core SEO extension `tx_seo`.

I configure the sitemap for events2 this way:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            sitemaps {
                events2 {
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        table =  tx_events2_domain_model_event
                        sortField = tstamp
                        lastModifiedField = tstamp
                        pid = 2061
                        recursive = 2
                        url {
                            pageId = 917 //PageID Detail Page
                            fieldToParameterMap {
                                uid = tx_events2_events[event]
                            }
                            additionalGetParameters {
                                tx_events2_events.controller = Day
                                tx_events2_events.action = show
                            }
                            useCacheHash = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The sitemap is generated and I can show the detail view. Google accepts the sitemap, too. But the URLs are ugly because the route enhancer is not used. This is my configuration of the route enhancer.

```
Events2Plugin:
type: Extbase
extension: Events2
plugin: Events
routes:
  - { routePath: '', _controller: 'Day::list' }
  - { routePath: '/{date}/{event_title}', _controller: 'Day::show', _arguments: { date: 'timestamp', event_title: 'event' }}
  - { routePath: '/events/{date}', _controller: 'Day::showByTimestamp', _arguments: { date: 'timestamp' }}
  - { routePath: '/{location}', _controller: 'Location::show', _arguments: { location: 'location' }}
  - { routePath: '/listpage-{page}', _controller: 'Day::list', _arguments: { page: '@widget_0/currentPage' }}
defaultController: 'Day::list'
defaults:
  page: '0'
requirements:
  date: '\d+-\d+-\d+_\d+'
  event_title: '^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$'
aspects:
  date:
    type: TimestampMapper
    format: Y-m-d_Hi
  event_title:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_events2_domain_model_event
    routeFieldName: path_segment
  location:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_events2_domain_model_location
    routeFieldName: slug
  page:
    type: StaticRangeMapper
    start: '1'
    end: '100'
```

What can I do that the route enhancer is used as with other extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RouteEnhancer configuration for detail view requires a {date}. You only add action and controller to URI in Sitemap configuration.

Please add

`tx_events2_events.timestamp = 0`

to section „additionalGetParameters“

Comment: With this solution the timestamp is '1970-01-01_0100'. Is there a way to get the original date and time of the event? @froemken